# Google Maps in Xamarin for Android fails to center on location

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation

```
        var _locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        var mapPosition = await _locator.GetPositionAsync();

        var mapSpan = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
            new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(mapPosition.Latitude, mapPosition.Longitude), 
            Distance.FromMiles(2)
            );

        Map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
```

Using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Postion() the correct lat and lon coordinates are calculated.

[image]

However, when I add it to MapSpan, the coordinates change to somewhere in the middle of the Atlantic ocean.  Not sure what is causing this?

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

So the problem is definitely in the Android project.  For some reason, GoogleMaps is not recognizing the location passed by the Map Renderer in the shared project.  OnMapReady is just using the default lat/lon.

[image]

SUCCESS!!!

```
        async Task<Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position> GetPositionAsync()
    {
        var _locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position myPosition = await _locator.GetPositionAsync();
        return myPosition;
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position myPosition = Task.Run(GetPositionAsync).Result;

        map = googleMap;
        map.MoveCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLng(
                new LatLng(myPosition.Latitude, myPosition.Longitude)));
        map.AnimateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.ZoomTo(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

The MapSpan properties `LatitudeDegree` and `LongitudeDegrees` refer to the degrees of latitude and longitude that are spanned (i.e. the number of degrees of the map that are shown within its view.)

If you are looking for the lat/lng of the center of the map in your span, refer to the `Center` properties which is a `Maps.Postion` object.

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.MapSpan/

Example:

```
var mapPosition = new Position(38.29, -77.45);
var mapSpan = MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(mapPosition, Distance.FromMiles(2));
map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
```

Comment: 1. The original 'mapPosition' is correct. That represents the exact location of the user (me). So there is nothing wrong with the lat/lon. 2. This code has been working in production for 2 years. Now, for some reason, it is returning a completely different result on Android. So, unless I am misunderstanding your answer, it doesn't appear that `Center` will help in this case.

Comment: @dizzyguy You are looking at the wrong properties, LatitudeDegree/LongitudeDegrees relate to the **size** of the map area displayed, not the lat/lng location of the map. Your 0.05/0.07 relate to the 2 mile radius

Comment: Ok, I hear you. Why is `Map.MoveToRegion(mapSpan)` centering on the radius' lat/lon as opposed to the `Center` lat/lon? I inspected the `mapSpan` object and indeed you are correct, the `Center` property shows the correct lat/lon, but when I say, `MoveToRegion()`, it centers on the spans radius lat/lon values and not the center. I'm confused as to why this used to work, and now it is moving to the wrong lat/lon. Can you provide a code sample of what should work? Something doesn't seem right...

Comment: It appears that perhaps `Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap` is the problem, possibly?  I think the `MoveToRegion` method is correct now.  But when I invoke `OnMapReady` in my Android project, GoogleMap appears to center on the wrong lat/lon.  I'm including a screen shot above.

Comment: @dizzyguy Are you trying to set the map location **before** OnMapReadyhas completed? As that will not work

Comment: It does appear so. I am trying to maintain this code, it was written by another developer. But yes, the `OnAppearingAsync` in the shared project is being invoked prior to `OnMapReady` in the Android project.  (However, I should add that this code was working for more than a year, and only recently stopped centering properly)

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, I finally figured it out.  I still don't know why it stopped working, but learned a few things in the process.